# Ending threads in java correctly

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with Threads in Java.
I would like to write a program where there is Class Main which has ArrayList of Threads of some class (Class Task) which just writes a letter and the number. Object Main just wakes one Thread from ArrayList and let it to do something while the same object(Main) sleeps another one. 
But there is one problem even if I change the Main.ACTIVE to false it does not end all of the Threads some stay on, and it's random, I just would like to make them end and write:

I am saying goodbay + character - sth like that

```
public class Main extends Thread {
    ArrayList<Thread> threads;
    static boolean ACTIVE = true;
    public Main() {
        super();
        threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    }

    public void run(){

        Object monitor = new Object();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            threads.add(new Thread(new Task(i + 65, monitor)));
        }

        long cT = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
            threads.get(i).start();
        }
        System.out.println("BEFORE synchronized(monitor)");
        synchronized(monitor){
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() - cT < 1000) {
                try{
                    monitor.notify();
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    monitor.wait();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();}
                }
                System.out.println("BEFORE ACTIVE= FALSE and after WHILE in Main");
                ACTIVE = false;
                for(int i  = 0; i < threads.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println(threads.get(i).getState());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("LAST COMMAND IN MAIN");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
        //new Thread(new Task(65)).start();
    }
}
```

And the Task Class

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    int nr;
    char character;
    Object monitor;

    public Task(int literaASCII, Object monitor) {
        this.nr = 0;
        this.monitor = monitor;
        character = (char) (literaASCII);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            while (Main.ACTIVE) {
                try {
                     System.out.println("ENTERING WHILE IN TASK");
                    monitor.wait();
                    System.out.print(nr + "" + character + ", ");
                    nr++;
                    int r = (int) ((Math.random() * 50) + 50); // <500ms,1000ms)
                    Thread.sleep(r);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                monitor.notify();
                 System.out.println("YYYYYYYYY");
            }
             System.out.println("AFTER WHILE IN Task");
        }
        System.out.println("I am saying goodbye " + character);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement thread pools by hand? There are a bunch of predefined thread pools implemented in the `Executors` class.

Comment: You should add the homework tag if it is applicable (which seems to be the case).

Comment: Not my homework it's my friend and I wanted to teach him the simple Thread management. I like other tools to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now naswer is

0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 0F, 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 1F, WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
LAST COMMAND IN MAIN

I added sleep after starting threads

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends Thread {
ArrayList<Thread> threads;
volatile static boolean ACTIVE = true;
public Main() {
    super();
    threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
}

 public void run(){

Object monitor = new Object();
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  threads.add(new Thread(new Task(i + 65, monitor)));
}

long cT = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
  threads.get(i).start();
}
try{Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
 //   System.out.println("BEFORE synchronized(monitor)");
synchronized(monitor){
  while (System.currentTimeMillis() - cT < 1000) {
      try{

    monitor.notify();
    Thread.sleep(500);

    monitor.wait();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
   //    System.out.println("BEFORE ACTIVE= FALSE and after WHILE in Main");
  ACTIVE = false;
  for(int i  = 0; i < threads.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(threads.get(i).getState());
  }


}
System.out.println("LAST COMMAND IN MAIN");

  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Main().start();
    //new Thread(new Task(65)).start();

}

}
```

and the TASK

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
int nr;
char character;
Object monitor;

public Task(int literaASCII, Object monitor) {
    this.nr = 0;
    this.monitor = monitor;
    character = (char) (literaASCII);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        while (Main.ACTIVE) {
            try {
//               System.out.println("ENTERING WHILE IN TASK");
                monitor.wait();
                System.out.print(nr + "" + character + ", ");
                nr++;
                int r = (int) ((Math.random() * 50) + 50); // <500ms,1000ms)

                Thread.sleep(r);
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            monitor.notify();
    //       System.out.println("YYYYYYYYY");
        }
         System.out.println("AFTER WHILE IN Task");
    }
    System.out.println("I am saying goodbye " + character);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you look at the more modern concurrency classes in `java.util.concurrent` package, especially `ExecutorService`.  And read "Java Concurrency In Practice."

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is for starters that `ACTIVE` should be marked as `volatile`.  Any variable that is shared by multiple threads needs to somehow be `synchronized` or marked as `volatile` so that it will have a memory barrier around its reading and writing.

Another thing you can do from a boolean standpoint is to use the `AtomicBoolean` class instead of a `volatile boolean`.

Instead of a `static volatile boolean`, you might instead consider to have a `volatile boolean` for each `Task` object so that `Main` has more fine grained control over the individual tasks and you are using a `static` "global" variable.  You could even add a `task.shutdown()` method to set the active flag.

Lastly, as @duffmo mentioned, you should always consider using one of the thread-pools `ExecutorService` if you always just want to have one thread running.   Something like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`.  But I can't quite tell if you only want one thread all of the time.  If you used an `ExecutorService` then `main` would just do:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    // the monitor would not be needed
    threadPool.submit(new Task(i + 65));
}
threadPool.shutdown();
for (Future future : futures) {
    // this waits for the working task to finish
    future.get();
}
```

But if you need your background task to stop and start like it is currently doing with the `monitor` then this model might not work.

Comment: I cannot use Executors Queues, Locks and similar. It is forbidden.
I changed ACTIVE to volatile but the effect stays the same

0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 2E, WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
BLOCKED
LAST COMMAND IN MAIN
AFTER WHILE IN Task
I am saying goodbye F

Comment: I'm a little surprised @Robert it runs at all.  Just because you call `start()` doesn't mean the thread will run immediately so chances are that `main` will be the first to synchronize on the monitor.  The first `notify` main does will do nothing since no one is waiting.  It will `sleep` and then `wait`.  Then all of the forked threads will run down to the `wait` call and the program will hang.  No one is left to call `notify`.  I guess it depends on how many threads start fast and beat `main` into the `wait()`.   Try sleeping in `main` after you start the threads.

Comment: Now the answer is always

0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 0F, 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 1F, WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
WAITING
LAST COMMAND IN MAIN
I am adding the code in the answer down the page